# Parsing String Timestamp as JODA TimeStamp

Tags: timezone, timestamp, jodatime

Given the following UTC time:

`2009-11-17 10:45:32`

How can I create an `org.jode.time.LocalDateTime` with that exact time, but in UTC?

In other words, that time-stamp represents a UTC time. I'd like to make a new Timestamp object in `joda` with that time in UTC.

I tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
scala> org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.parse("2009-11-17 10:45:32", 
                                          org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.tTime)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2009-11-17 10:45:32"
```

Comment: "2009-11-17 10:45:32" isn't a UTC time - it doesn't have *any* offset specified. It's just a `LocalDateTime` as specified. I don't see what time zones have to do with this question at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem here is just the lack of a `T` in the value. Note that the idea of "a `LocalDateTime` [...] but in UTC" is meaningless. A `LocalDateTime` value *has* no time zone.

The simplest fix is probably just to create a `DateTimeFormatter` from a pattern:

```
// Java code, but Scala should be similar
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime dateTime = format.parseLocalDateTime(value);
```

You can create the `DateTimeFormatter` once and store it in a static final variable - `DateTimeFormatter` is thread-safe (unlike `SimpleDateFormat`, for example.)

Comment: Thank you! I should've read the [docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html): `LocalDateTime is an unmodifiable datetime class representing a datetime without a time zone.`.